# Specifying custom RunListener in AndroidManifest metadata not working

Tags: android, junit, android-manifest, metadata, android-instrumentation

**Goal**

To have a custom `RunListener` do custom things on test failure when running Android instrumentation tests using Espresso.

**tl;dr**

`InstrumentationInfo.metaData` is `null`, even while `ApplicationInfo.metaData` has my info. Why?

**Progress thus far**

I can get my RunListener to work with the following adb command:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e listener com.myproject.test.runlisteners.CustomRunListener -e class com.myproject.test.ui.HomeActivityTest#testWillFail com.myproject.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Which is specified in the documentation for AndroidJUnitRunner [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html).

However, that documentation also states that one can specify a RunListener in an `AndroidManifest.xml` metadata element. I have thus far been unsuccessful getting this to work.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

I added the following to my `<application>` element in `main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="listener"
        android:value="com.myproject.test.runlisteners.CustomRunListener" />
```

This didn't have any effect. By various means, I  have discovered that these lines of code (which are used by `AndroidJUnitRunner` and `RunnerArgs` to get custom metadata arguments from the manifest)

```
InstrumentationInfo instrInfo = pm.getInstrumentationInfo(
    getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle b = instrInfo.metaData;
```

...return me a `null` Bundle.

I noticed that the generated `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` didn't have my metadata tag, and so, as an experiment, I also added it to my `androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` file. That looks like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".BaseApplication">

    <meta-data
        android:name="listener"
        android:value="com.sirius.test.runlisteners.CustomRunListener" />

</application>
```

...which then appears in the generated `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<application android:name="com.myproject.BaseApplication" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="listener"
        android:value="com.sirius.test.runlisteners.CustomRunListener" />

    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
```

This also didn't have any effect.

**Another experiment**

I created a custom test runner called `CustomAndroidJUnitRunner` which extends AndroidJUnitRunner just for the purpose of peaking under the hood a bit. If I do this:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(
    getComponentName().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle b = ai.metaData;
Object o = b.get("listener");
Log.d(TAG, "listener=" + o.toString());
```

...logcat will say:

```
D/CustomAndroidJUnitRunner: listener=com.myproject.test.runlisteners.CustomRunListener
```

So, `ApplicationInfo.metaData` has it. Why doesn't `InstrumentationInfo.metaData`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes it's not until you've taken the time to explain everything thoroughly that you finally understand what the problem is. The solution is to add this to the `<manifest>` element:

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="com.myproject.test.runner.CustomAndroidJUnitRunner"
    android:functionalTest="false"
    android:handleProfiling="false"
    android:label="Tests for com.myproject"
    android:targetPackage="com.myproject">

    <meta-data
        android:name="listener"
        android:value="com.myproject.test.runlisteners.CustomRunListener" />

</instrumentation>
```

I just copy-pasted the `<instrumentation>` element from the generated `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I was a bit thrown off, originally, because both `CustomAndroidJUnitRunner` and `com.myproject` were highlighted in red in Android Studio. But everything compiles just fine.

I hope this helps someone else!